# Spring data jpa and json query

Tags: json, mongodb, java-8, spring-data-jpa

Got a json request body as follow:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "phoneNumber": "0123456789"
}
```

I want to search the related entry in MongoDB, even if a field is missing, in which case, the missing field must match any values.

For example, the following query will search all entries having a matching firstName:

```
{
  "firstName": "John"
}
```

While the previous JSON will have to match all the 3 parameters. If one of the 3 value is blank, then it should include blank in the search.
But if a key-value pair is missing, like in the second JSON, it has to match any value for that key.

**Questions**

1. Should I write a finder for all combinations?
   E.g. something like:

```java
@Repository
    List<Phonebook.Entry> findAllEntries();
    @Query("{firstName : ?0, lastName: ?1}")
    List<Phonebook.Entry> findEntryByName(String firstName, String lastName);
    @Query("{firstName : ?0}")
    List<Phonebook.Entry> findEntryByFirstName(String firstName);
    @Query("{lastName : ?0}")
    List<Phonebook.Entry> findEntryByLastName(String lastName);
    @Query("{phoneNumber : ?0}")
    List<Phonebook.Entry> findEntryByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
    @Query("{firstName : ?0, phoneNumber : ?1}")
    List<Phonebook.Entry> findEntryByFirstNameAndPhoneNumber(String firstName, String phoneNumber);
    @Query("{lastName : ?0, phoneNumber : ?1}")
    List<Phonebook.Entry> findEntryByLastNameAndPhoneNumber(String lastName, String phoneNumber);
    @Query("{firstName : ?0, lastName : ?1, phoneNumber : ?2}")
    List<Phonebook.Entry> findEntryByLastNameAndFirstNameAndPhoneNumber(String firstName, String lastName,String phoneNumber);
}
```

2. How do I transform the query to do a "like" search instead?
   For example, the following JSON would return all the entry with the first name starting with "Jo" instead of the exact value as in question 1.

```
{
  "firstName": "Jo"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Definitly don't do that. Combining params like that is always bad idea.
2. Take a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb) in 3.4 section how to simulate `LIKE`. Your method should look something like `findByFirstNameLikeOrLastNameLikeOrPhoneNumberLike(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber)` . When passing arguments to this method, you should pass `empty String` instead of `null`. Maybe this method is not really good from performance side.

Also, take a look at `findByExample` method described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.usage) .